# Problema con el login utilizando $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, mysql

El problema en el que me encuentro es el siguiente: Estoy realizando un sistema en el cual hay departamentos (comunicación, sistemas, etc) y cada usuario esta registrado respecto al departamento que depende, entonces, quiero que cuando un usuario de comunicacion intente ingresar a la vista de sistemas no se lo permita porque no está registrado a ese departamento, anexo el codigo

**HTML**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (($_SESSION["usuario"])!="" and $_SESSION["departamento"]=="Sistemas"){
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bienvenidos | Sistemas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]?></h1>
    <a href="../../private/cerrar_sesion.php"><button type="buttom" class="btn-regresar">Cerrar sesion</button></a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}else{
?>
<h2>favor de iniciar session o reportar al Administrador</h2> <br>
<a href="../../iniciar_sesion.html"><button type="button" class="btn-regresar">Iniciar sesion</button></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

***Sesion***

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ?>
        <?php
//importamos el archivo conexion para evitar escribir mas codigo
include "conexion.php";
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña=$_POST['contraseña'];
// $departamento="SELECT departamento FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$_POST[usuario]' and contraseña = '$_POST[contraseña]'";
//consulta para detectar los datos del usuario
$consulta="SELECT nivel,usuario,contraseña, estado, nombre, departamento FROM usuarios WHERE 
usuario='$_POST[usuario]' and contraseña = '$_POST[contraseña]'";
    $result=$conexion->query($consulta);
    if ($result->num_rows>0){ }
    $rows=($result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    $mensaje = $rows[usuario];
    // $result1=$conexion->query($departamento);
    // if($result1->num_rows>0){ }
    // $rows1=($result1->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC));
    // $departamento1= $rows1[departamento];
    
    if($usuario==$rows['usuario'] and $contraseña==$rows['contraseña']){
        $_SESSION['loggedin']=true;
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
        $_SESSION['departamento']="SELECT departamento FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$_POST[usuario]' and contraseña = '$_POST[contraseña]'";
        $_SESSION['start']=time();
        $_SESSION['expire']=$_SESSION['start']*(5*60);

    
        // Si el usuario es administrador lo redireccionamos a la pagina que corresponde
    if($rows['nivel']=="Administrador" && $rows['estado']== "Activo"){
        header("Location: ../users/sistemas/index.php?nombre=$mensaje");
        
//Redireccionamos de acuerdo al departamento que corresponde cada docente
    }else if($rows['nivel']=="Docente" && $rows['estado']== "Activo" && $rows['departamento']== "Electromecanica"){
        header("Location: ../users/electromecanica/inicio.php?nombre=$mensaje");

    }else if($rows['nivel']=="Docente" && $rows['estado']== "Activo" && $rows['departamento']== "Bioquimica"){
        header("Location: ../users/bioquimica/inicio.php?nombre=$mensaje");

    }else if($rows['nivel']=="Docente" && $rows['estado']== "Activo" && $rows['departamento']== "Comunicacion"){
        header("Location: ../users/comunicacion/inicio.php?nombre=$mensaje");

    }else if($rows['nivel']=="Administrador" and $rows['estado']== "Inactivo" ){
        echo $rows[usuario]." Tu cuenta esta Inactiva consulta al Administrador";
    }else if($rows['nivel']=="Docente" and $rows['estado']== "Inactivo" ){
        echo $rows[usuario]." Tu cuenta esta Inactiva consulta al Administrador";
    }
    }else if($username!=$rows['username']){
        echo "<h1>Este usuario no existe</h1>";
        echo "<center>"."<h5>"."<a href='../iniciar_sesion.html'><button class='btn boton-peligro'>INICIO</button></a>"."</h5>."."</center>";
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Tengo comentados algunas lineas porque estuve intentando de algunas formas pero no lo logré, espero que me puedan ayudar, seria de mucha ayuda

Comment: Lo que yo haria, tengo un sistemita parecido, es crear un objeto usuario y agregarlo a una variable de session de nombre user, entonces ahi le agregaria su "departamento" y luego en la vista que vas a presentar al loggear, en la cabecera verifica que el departamento corresponda

Comment: de la misma manera que evitaria un acceso no autorizado, yo tengo algo asi en mis cabeceras de vistas protegidas: 
$this->user = is_logged();    
    if (!$this->user) {
      redirect("/");
    }

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de gran ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es simple, tu variable de sesion relativa al departamento esta mal asignada:

```
 $_SESSION['departamento']="SELECT departamento FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$_POST[usuario]' and contraseña = '$_POST[contraseña]'";

// lo correcto es:
 $_SESSION['departamento']= $row["departamento"];
```

Asegurate tambien de que el case en el if se corresponda con la sesion:

```
session_start();
if (($_SESSION["usuario"])!="" and lcase($_SESSION["departamento"])==lcase("Sistemas")){...
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Estás en lo correcto, lo corregi a tiempo pero gracias por tu aporte, asi como lo indicaste es la forma correcta. Gracias por tu aporte, saludos